# how to programmatically post a comment on Facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I am noob to Facebook api, let me explain this in more detail, I have gone through graph api, I am able to post a comment using correct access token via graph explorer, all works fine.

my question is that I see a post on Facebook wall, I want my app to post a comment on this post, how does my app know the post_id of this post, are there any ways to get post id of latest post, or for last 10 posts or some other way.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To [read the recent feeds](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed/) of a user-

   ```
   \GET /<user-id>/feed
   ```

   with this, you'll get the posts and their details (id, objectid, type message, description etc.) You can use the Graph API Explorer to check.
2. To [post a comment](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/comments/) on a post-

   ```
   \POST /<object-id>/
   message=This+is+a+test+comment
   attachment_url=.....
   ```

   `object-id` be the `object-id` for photos and `id` for feeds.

You can go through the [API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/) to see what all APIs are available.

Answer (score 1):

For those of who stumble upon this post after April 24th, Facebook has stopped support for such API calls.

> As of April 24,2018, the publish_actions permission has been removed. Please see the [Breaking Changes Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24) for more details. To provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our [Sharing products](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing) instead.